# Display message during make install using automake

Tags: gnu, autotools, autoconf, automake

Using **gnu automake** how do I **display a custom message** to the user during the ***make install*** stage?

I have been reading the [automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html) and various other tutorials but have not yet found an answer, it may just be hidden somewhere in the manual and I failed to find it. Please point it out if you where it's explained.

I am converting some source to use automake and near the end stage of ***make install*** I would like to display a message to tell the user they should run a particular script to set up some extra things that shouldn't be part of a automake, or can not (easily) be done in an install-data-hook or something.

Additionally is there actually a clean way to run a custom script using automake (outside of install hooks and such)? I can imagine it's big nono so I am not seriously considering it, but I am curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply include an install hook in your Makefile.am file:

```
 install-exec-hook:
         echo "Do this other thing now"
```

> Additionally is there actually a clean way to run a custom script
>   using automake (outside of install hooks and such)?

Install hooks are exactly what that is for.

```
 http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending-Installation.html
```

Comment: That was too obvious so I missed it (using echo), thanks. As for the second part, yes I figured install hooks is all that is needed. The script that a user would need to run falls outside of what automake should do so using echo to notify the user will suffice.